# call a script in Python 2 and Python 3 is different?

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'E:\Python')
from hypy import htj
tD = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
x = 0.1
sD, _ = htj.dls_array(np.array([x]), tD)
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'htj'

When I run the above code in Spyder Python (version 3.8), I get the result. However, I have difficulty running it in the ArcGIS Desktop Python (version 2), where I need to run it.

`hypy` folder is inside `E:\Python`.
`htj.py` is a script having `dls_array` function located inside the hypy folder.

"_" after sD is with some purpose.

Please suggest a way to handle it as I cannot switch from ArcGIS Desktop to ArcGIS Pro Python due to software unavailability.

Comment: In `hypy/` is there an `__init__.py`?  Try also `sys.path.insert(0, r'E:\Python')` to make sure it's first on the path and not being overridden by something else. In general you should not be using `sys.path` manipulations, and instead install your package to a standard path location. But we'll cross that bridge later...

Comment: @Iguananaut Yes, there is an __init__.py file inside folder hypy.  I tried with sys.path.insert(0,r'E:\Python') but I receved same error. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'htj'.

Comment: Try just running `import hypy` by itself, then in your code `print(hypy)` to see where the module is being imported from.

Comment: @Iguananaut >>> import hypy
>>> print(hypy)
<module 'hypy' from 'E:\Python\hypy\__init__.pyc'>  This is what I received after running as per your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you run `import hypy.htj`?  (please try to enclose things like paths in backticks `so it looks like this` and doesn't end up with weird formatting), so we can see *exactly* what your output is.

Comment: @Iguananaut same problem persist with `import hypy.htj`. I think the command line to call a function differs in Python 2 than Python 3?

Comment: This has nothing to do with calling a function.  Are you sure the file `E:\Python\hypy\htj.py` exists (and not just the `.pyc` file)?

Comment: @Iguananaut I am pasting here the details of object properties of file htj.py. Object name:‪`E:\Python\hypy\htj.py`

Comment: What I asked is if the file exists...

Comment: @Iguananaut Yes, it exists and it is running in Spyder Python 3.8 but not in ArcGIS Desktop Python console (Python version is 2 in ArcGIS Desktop).

Comment: In Spyder can you please show the output of `import hypy.htj; print(hypy.htj)`?

Comment: @Iguananaut `runfile('E:/Python/hypy/test_htj.py', wdir='E:/Python/hypy')
Reloaded modules: hypy.hypy, hypy.ths, hypy.jcb, hypy.script, hypy.thc, hypy.thn, hypy.pcw, hypy.blt, hypy.war, hypy, hypy.htj
<module 'hypy.htj' from 'E:\\Python\\hypy\\htj.py'>` The result of running in spyder

Comment: When you run it in ArcGIS what is the output of `print(sys.path)`?

Comment: @Iguananaut  `['E:\\Python', '', u'c:\\program files (x86)\\arcgis\\desktop10.8\\arcpy', .............'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\lib\\site-packages', 'E:\\Python', 'E:\\Python\\hypy', 'E:\\Python', 'E:/Python', 'E:/Python', 'E:/Python/hypy', 'E:/Python', 'E:\\Python']
` I deleted middle portion because it was out of range for the comment box.

Comment: That's pretty weird.  It really should work, if `E:\Python\hypy\htj.py` is really there.  It is *possible* that you are missing some other dependencies the import would fail, but you would more likely get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for the missing dependency.  I found the [hypy](https://github.com/Raghwendra11/hypy) package you appear to be using on GitHub, and it does not contain an `htj` module, so without knowing where that module came from this is impossible to try to reproduce.

Comment: @Iguananaut `htj.py` script has been prepared by my supervisor recently. It is not uploaded on GitHub yet. However, I have `htj.py` file in the `hypy` folder of my computer.

Comment: You may wish to ask your supervisor. I don't think this problem can be solved without some hands-on debugging of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Make sure you have a `__init__.py` empty file in folder `E:\Python`
2. Try to explicite say `from .hypy import htj`
3. Try: `from hypy.htj import dls_array` and then use `dls_array` without `htj.`
   4 Most important: Try to avoid using Python2.